# best way to find a non-existent value

Tags: sql-server

We have an mssql table System.dbo.DirectMapping that has a filed, account.  Not sure whether you saw my other question, but they are not unique.  Before I asked the best way to get an account that exists.  Now I need to find one that does not exist.  I read a way to generate the numbers from 1 - to 1000 so my strategy was to find a number in that range which is not in the DirectMapping table.  This works, but is cumbersome.  I wonder whether there is a more expedient way to do it?

```
SELECT num from (
SELECT ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1000*thousands.n as num
FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
 (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n),
 (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) hundreds(n),
 (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) thousands(n)) j
where j.num not in (select account from System.dbo.DirectMapping)
```

Comment: Are you just looking for a unique number in your db to assign it to a new row?

Comment: What is your ultimate objective? Your current trajectory seems odd.

Comment: Yes, I have to enter a form and get the result "account not found".  So I need to find an account that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job for you

```
with a as (
select  row_number() over(order by account) as rownum from System.dbo.DirectMapping)
select * from a
where rownum not in (select account from System.dbo.DirectMapping) and rownum <1000
```

OR

```
select a.rownum from (select  row_number() over(order by account) as rownum from System.dbo.DirectMapping) a
where a.rownum not in (select account from System.dbo.DirectMapping) and a.rownum <1000
```

Once you used all the numbers in account that are less than 1000, you can replace the

```
a.rownum <1000
```

with

```
 a.rownum >=1000 and  a.rownum <2000
```

or any other range you want to check for

In case someone came here trying to do this in oracle it is even simpler

```
    select rownum from System.dbo.DirectMapping 
where rownum <1000 and rownum not in (select account from System.dbo.DirectMapping)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question.

Assuming AccountID is an INT, and you want to find missing IDs or gaps.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (AccountID int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1),(1),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)   -- Notice 2,3,4 are missing in non-distinct list

Select MissingIDs = A.N
 From (
        Select Top (Select max(AccountID) from @YourTable) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (select null)) 
        From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
      ) A
 Left Join @YourTable B  on A.N=B.AccountID
 Where B.AccountID is null
```

**Returns the Missing AccountIDs**

```
MissingIDs
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer:

Create a table `accounts_temp` that only has one column with all numbers expected to be in the account column in your `DirectMapping` table and use this to find your missing ones

```
select min(account) from accounts_temp where account not in (
select account from System.dbo.DirectMapping)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 select max(account)+1
 from System.dbo.DirectMapping
```

Assuming account is numeric, query above will always return a non-existent value

Comment: Can you give me some explanation of how this answers the question?

Comment: Query wil always return a non-existent value as questioned.
For example if max(account) return 10, then 11 is not existing, otherwise max(account) would return 11.
Assuming account is numeric ofcourse.

Comment: Apologies, I was referring to expanding your answer to include additional information as the answer came up in the review queue as being short.  In general SO prefers answers to have explanation in addition to code.